# AzureAD as Identity Provider for IBM Cloud - Name Not recognised

Tags: ibm-appid

I have setup AzuerAD as identity provider and everything is working except below:

1. Display name is reflecting as "notset notset" rather "UserActualFirstName UserActualLastName". Azure attributes has user.mail, user.givenname, user.userprincipalname and user.surname
2. Created trusted profile with an access group and onboard user is set to static.
   User is still onboarded with "notset notset" name and no access group assigned.

My user details - notset notset
Status - Active

Trusted profile fedrated condition rule:

1. email CONTAINS "abc.onmicrosoft.com"
2. mail CONTAINS "abc.onmicrosoft.com"
3. username CONTAINS "abc.onmicrosoft.com"

It should work as expected.